# it doesn't work by using MutableData.value in Android

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

```
class CounterViewModel: ViewModel() {

  val count = MutableLiveData<Integer>()

  fun increase() {
      count.value = count.value + 1
  }

  fun decrease() { 

  }
}
```

and the 'count.value = count.value + 1' doesn't work.
why can't i use plus in that code?

Comment: i found out the reason, i had to make the MutableLiveData<Int> it's not Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count.value` is a nullable that is why is not working. Replace it with

```
  count.value = (count.value ?: 0) + 1
```

0 is the fallback if value is null